# PyGObject: Scale/Range as Gtk MenuItem?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm trying to create a volume application indicator in linux using python but I couldn't find a way to use a Gtk.Scale as child of Gtk.MenuItem. I could add Gtk.Scale object as child but the Scale widget will not be able to capture my mouse click.

Is there anyway of doing this?

Here is the simplified code to add Gtk.Scale to Gtk.MenuItem:

```
import gi
import signal
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
APPINDICATOR_ID = 'VolControl'

class volumeapplet:
    def main(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
        self.indicator = appindicator.Indicator.new(APPINDICATOR_ID, 'audio-volume-high', appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
        self.indicator.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
        self.indicator.set_menu(self.build_menu())
        Gtk.main()

    def build_menu(self):
        menu = Gtk.Menu()

        # volume control
        slider_item = Gtk.MenuItem.new()
        slider = Gtk.Scale.new_with_range(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL,0.0,100.0,1.0)
        slider_item.add(slider)
        menu.append(slider_item)

        menu.append(Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem())

        menu.show_all()
        return menu

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = volumeapplet()
    app.main()
```

Comment: You want the scale _in_ your menu?

Comment: Yes. For volume control

Comment: You may be able to pass the signals from the menu item to the scale, but I wouldn't bet on it. In fact, to do that without getting all mouse clicks in the menu item, you may need a callback that handles the mouse events, then induces a scale signal.

Comment: I need to do this too. Did you have any luck with it?

Comment: @raj, too bad, no...